# Split DataFrame into Chunks according to time or index differences

Tags: python, pandas

i'm trying to separate a DataFrame into smaller DataFrames according to the Index value or Time. As you can see in the example below, the time resolution of my data is 5 min, and i would like to create a new dataframe when the time difference between each row is greater than 5 min, or when the Index grows more than 1 (which is the same criteria, so any would work).

Here is an example of my data:

```
Index    Time     Data
0        6:00      A
1        6:05      D
2        6:10      B
58       10:50     C
59       10:55     A
60       11:00     D
92       13:40     A
93       13:45     B
```

And i would like to have the following:

Split 1:

```
Index    Time     Data
0        6:00      A
1        6:05      D
2        6:10      B
```

Split 2:

```
Index    Time     Data
58       10:50     C
59       10:55     A
60       11:00     D
```

Split 3:

```
Index    Time     Data
92       13:40     A
93       13:45     B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a helper series like:

```
s=df.index.to_series().diff().fillna(1).ne(1).cumsum()
print(s)
Index
0     0
1     0
2     0
58    1
59    1
60    1
92    2
93    2
```

Then you can store each group in a dictionary and call each key of the dict to refer the df:

```
d={f'df_{i}':g for i,g in df.groupby(s)}
```

---

```
print(d['df_0'])
print('\n')
print(d['df_1'])
print('\n')
print(d['df_2'])
```

---

```
       Time Data
Index           
0      6:00    A
1      6:05    D
2      6:10    B


        Time Data
Index            
58     10:50    C
59     10:55    A
60     11:00    D


        Time Data
Index            
92     13:40    A
93     13:45    B
```

Another way using `more_itertools`:

```
from more_itertools import consecutive_groups
indices=[[*i] for i in consecutive_groups(df.index)]
#[[0, 1, 2], [58, 59, 60], [92, 93]]
d2={f'df_{e}':df.loc[i] for e,i in enumerate(indices)}
```

Comment: Hi, your answer works excellently but could you please explain what the .ne() and the .cumsum() part does? I tried following step by step but can't seem to figure out how the column generated by .ne() results in the column with different values using .cumsum() when the index is not continuous.

Comment: @user42 when `ne(1)` checks if the difference is not equal to 1. Hence wherever the difference is not 1 it returns True, and cumsum keeps adding 1 wherever it finds the next True value, Hence we get a grouper column. You can also use the `more_itertools` based solution.

Answer (score 0):

One more approach (based on an earlier answer on stackoverflow, can't find the link now)

```
group=[]
for k,g in df.groupby(df['Index'] - np.arange(df.shape[0])):
    group.append(g)
```

You can then access individual group/dataframe with
    `group[0], group[1] or group[2]`